# Is there a simple way to do tiered coin rounding using standard Cocoa libraries?

Tags: cocoa-touch, internationalization, nsdecimalnumber

[In 2012, Canada abolished the 1¢ penny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_(Canadian_coin)#Abolition). To allow cash transactions to be processed at a 5¢ resolution, the following rounding policy was put into place:

> The calculation of the Goods and Services Tax (GST) or Harmonized Sales Tax (HST) on purchases, whether for cash or non-cash transactions, will continue to be calculated to the penny and added to the price. It is only the total cash payment for the transaction that will be rounded.

<sup>From [Royal Canadian Mint](http://www.mint.ca/store/mint/about-the-mint/rounding-6900008#.V0SqNpMrKsw).</sup>

That is, all calculations should be done as accurately as possible and end up using standard "[round half-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up) tie breaking to achieve hundredths resolution, but when it comes time to make the cash payment, further rounding to the nearest nickel is required.

For internationalization, I need to implement this. I also would like to re-use this for other places where, say, the final cost is rounded to 10¢, 25¢, etc. **How do I accomplish this behavior in iOS, using `NSDecimalNumber`s?**

I'd love if it worked like this on Obj-C:

```
finalCost = [total roundWithResolution:@0.05];
```

or this in Swift:

```
finalCost = total.roundWithResolution(0.05);
```

---

To clear up any ambiguity above, this is the behavior **after** having already rounded to the hundredths place using "round half-up" tie breaking:

#### 5¢

- $0.98 to $1.02 → $1.00
- $1.03 to $1.07 → $1.05
- $1.08 to $1.10 → $1.10
- And so on

#### 10¢

- $0.96 to $1.05 → $1.00
- $1.06 to $1.15 → $1.10
- And so on

#### 25¢

- $0.88 to $1.12 → $1.00
- $1.13 to $1.37 → $1.25
- $1.38 to $1.62 → $1.50
- $1.63 to $1.87 → $1.75
- $1.88 to $2.12 → $2.00
- And so on

Comment: What method of rounding is done for the "cash payment" part?  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding )

Comment: @bgp The standard, Round Half Up.

Comment: @bgp edited to be more clear

Comment: Not sure, but did you check out NSDecimalNumberHandler?

Comment: @bgp That doesn't seem to do what I need. If you think it can, please elaborate in an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Took me a night's worth of asking around and testing solutions, but I finally came up with this:

```
@implementation NSDecimalNumber (RoundWithResolution)

- (NSDecimalNumber *)roundWithResolution:(NSDecimalNumber *)resolution
{
    NSDecimalNumber *step1 = [self decimalNumberByDividingBy:resolution];
    NSDecimalNumber *step2 = [step1 round:0];
    NSDecimalNumber *step3 = [step2 decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:resolution];
    NSDecimalNumber *step4 = [step3 round:2];
    return step4;
}

- (NSDecimalNumber *)round:(NSUInteger)decimalPlaces
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    formatter.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp;
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = decimalPlaces;
    return [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[formatter stringFromNumber:self]];
}

@end
```

This is based off [this formula on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1798910/317419) by kccu, Milo Brandt, and Eric Towers:

> [image: f(n,m)=floor((n/m)+0.5)*m]